# Saving and Loading in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on this project for school and I have a some questions on it. My current goal right now is to implement a save and load method. When the save method is called, it saves the 2d array into a 1d array (it's in a form of a excel spreadsheet) and when it's asked to load, it displays the saved spreadsheet.

I know that I want to first save my 2d array of information into the 1d array, but how does it know how big the 1d array should be? I  know that I should have a nested for loop that goes through every part of my 2d array.

Is there any hints you guys can provide on how to proceed with creating these methods?

This is part of my code:

```
 public class Sheet implements Savable {
public int rows;
public int cols;
Cell [][] contents;
String alph = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

public Sheet (int rows, int cols) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    contents = new Cell [rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            contents[i][j] = new EmptyCell();
        }
    }
}

public String[] getSaveData() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If you're passed a 2D array that you don't know the sizes of (ex. `int[][] arr`), you can get the dimensions of the first array using something along the lines of `int rows = arr.length` and then the second dimension using `int cols = arr[num].length` where `0<=num<rows`. This assumes that the array has been initialized, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean a 1D array of char, which is a String, or a 1D array of String, which is a String[].  I'll assume you meant the first. If rows and cols do not change from run to run, then you don't need to save them with the data. Use a StringBuilder.

```
public String getSaveData() {
    StringBuilder saveData = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = o; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            saveData.append(contents[i][j].toString());
        }
    }
    return saveData.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now this is based on assumptions as there is not much useful information to go by, but I'm assuming that you are taking about implementing the method `getSaveData()`, which gets the data from the `Cells` in a form to save it to file.

Some hints:

1. The method declaration is that it returns an array of Strings - So you are going to have to create an array of strings in that method which will be the same size as the number of rows
2. You will need some form of a delimiting the data in each String so you can read it back in. A common one is a comma (unless you have commas in your cells)

   [Lookup about CSV files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)
3. As you loop append each cell contents to the String with the delimiter

Pseudo code for the method:

```
Create Array of size = number of rows
  For each row
     Create an empty String
     For each column
        Append cell contents to String and also a delimiter (take care if it's the last cell however!)
     Put the String in the array
return the array
```